# BeautifulSoup returns None eventhough there is something there

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

[image]

I'm trying to extract the information about the "Shares Outstanding" in the Investing.com

when I use the "Copy selector" by using the right-click of the mouse, it gives:

```
    #leftColumn > div.clear.overviewDataTable.overviewDataTableWithTooltip > div:nth-child(14) > span.float_lang_base_2.bold
```

by using this, I tried the BeautifulSoup code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request as req


    res = req.Request("https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    response = req.urlopen(res).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

    num_shares = soup.select("#leftColumn > div.clear.overviewDataTable.overviewDataTableWithTooltip > div:nth-child(14) > span.float_lang_base_2.bold")
    print(num_shares)
```

But the result gives: `[]` As there is nothing there.

How to solve this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May just be easier to use regex to find that class value. Then search for the particular text and grab the next sibling element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc'
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

overviewTbl = soup.find('div', {'class': re.compile(r"overviewDataTable")})
value = overviewTbl.find(text='Shares Outstanding').parent.next_sibling.text
```

**Output:**

```
print (value)
4,334,335,000
```

**Using `.select`**

But to use selector, I think using `nth-of-type` works instead of `nth-child`. Or at least it does for me.

```
num_shares = soup.select("div.clear.overviewDataTable.overviewDataTableWithTooltip > div:nth-of-type(14) > span.float_lang_base_2.bold")
print(num_shares)
```

**Output:**

```
[<span class="float_lang_base_2 bold">4,334,335,000</span>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude appreciate it